# How Can I Recover My Stolen Bitcoin

Tags: fraud

I need help on how to hire a legitimate recovery firm that can help recover my stolen bitcoin.

Comment: Please I need honest answers

Comment: Beware: there are MANY scammers that will masquerade as 'legitimate recovery firms'. They will promise a return of your funds, but in reality they are just looking to fleece you for even more money.

Comment: Thanks but are there real legitimate recovery companies out there?